# Static method calling result of mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I have

```
class Check
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new Database();
    }

    public function query()
    {
        $login = Session::get("login");
        $sth = $this->db->prepare('SELECT admin FROM accounts WHERE login=:login');
        $sth->execute(array(':login' => $login));
        $result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
        return $result[0];
    }

    public static function admin()
    {
        echo self::query();
    }
}
```

I have Database class in another place with PDO connection.

```
class Database extends PDO
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=name','root','pass');
        $this->query('SET NAMES utf8');
    }
}
```

So after Check::admin() code I get error:

> Undefined property: View::$db

Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using a `static` method, that wants to use a `instance` variable.

Your admin method calls the query method, and the query method is using the `db` instance variable. As your class is not instantiated, the `db` variable does not exists.

My suggestion would be to make the admin method non static and use your code like this:

```
$mycheck = new Check();
$mycheck->admin();
```

or, if you are on php 5.4 and want to stick with a oneliner:

```
(new Check())->admin();
```

**update**

note: Do not create the `db` class in the constructor, but inject it:

```
public function __construct(Database $db)
{
   $this->db = $db;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But my task is it use a static method. I should do query in mysql and get result: user is admin or not.

Comment: Well if you want to access a instance variable over a static method, instantiate the class: `$mycheck = new Check(); $mycheck::admin();` This is bad programming. If you are doing a course that teaches you this, get a refund.

Comment: I have self-education. Thanks for your opinion! I just want make possibility to call method like a static without instance. Less code, u know. But if u said that its bad programming I will change my code.

Comment: statics in classes are a fancy way to write procedural code. Better do it the OOP way. You will benefit a lot from that as you are moving on.

Comment: Yep. Im agree with u. But what if I need often to check user: he is admin or not? All time I should create a new instance?

Comment: Depends, in this case create a instance once, use multiple times. Sometimes it is easier to create multiple instances.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this is not direct answer for your question but your code has some issues so take some time and examine this and ask if it's not clear for you.

```
<?php

class Check {
    protected $_db;

    public function __construct(Database $db) {
        $this->_db = $db;
    }

    public function query(ISession $sessionData) {
        //WHY IS THE SESSION STATIC?
        //$login = Session::get("login");
        $sth = $this->_db->Connection()->prepare('SELECT admin FROM accounts WHERE login=:login');
        $sth->execute(array(':login' => $sessionData->get("login")));
        $result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
        return $result[0];
    }

    public function admin(ISession $sessionData) {
        // REALLY BAD TO ECHO HERE
        echo $this->query($sessionData);
    }
}

class Database {

    private $_name;
    private $_password;
    private $_connStr;
    private $_settings;

    private $_pdo;

    public function __construct($connstr, $name, $password, array $settings = array()) {
        $this->_name = $name;
        $this->_password = $password;
        $this->_connStr = $connstr;
        $this->_settings = $settings;
    }

    public function Connection() {
        if ($this->_pdo == NULL) {
            $this->_pdo = new PDO($this->_connStr, $this->_name, $this->_password);
        }

        return $this->_pdo;
    }

    /* other fancy methods */

    public function Close() {
        $this->_pdo = NULL;
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        $this->Close();
    }
}
```

And i don't see why you need a Check class for all this becouse if i were you i would create somethinf like this:

```
$currentSession = Session::GetCurrent();
$currentSession->User()->IsInRole('admin');
```

Note that the session is not static and if i would write a more complete solution i would avoid Session::GetCurrent() call becouse the current session would be a field in some class' instance (HttpApplication for example).

Comment: Session is static because I have another class Session ;)
Echo in admin() I had for test. Im agree with u that its so bad :)
Databse class I have in another file. There only PDO connection. And I manually change username, password and dbname of mysql. So it is why I didnt used a private variables diffirent. Thanks for ur help!